# Return listview value from ItemTapped to filter firebase call - Selected item returns as null

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I have tried adding the data to Listview using the public class 'Videotag' and a list 'initialList'. I'm trying to compare the listview selected item value to tags data from the RealtimeFirebase. The data from the firebase calls fine, but selected item value from listview returns null. Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

```
 public partial class videosection : ContentPage
    {
        List<videos> allVideos = new List<videos>();
        List<Videotag> item = new List<Videotag>();
        //List<string> initialList = new List<string>();

        public videosection()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //DependencyService.Get<IRotate>().ForcePortrait();

            //initialList.Add("Shoulders");
            //initialList.Add("Core");
            //initialList.Add("Arms");
            //initialList.Add("Hands");
            //initialList.Add("Legs");
            //initialList.Add("Balance");
            //VideoLV.ItemsSource = initialList;
            item.Add(new Videotag() { tags = "Shoulders" });
            item.Add(new Videotag() { tags = "Core" });
            item.Add(new Videotag() { tags = "Arms" });
            item.Add(new Videotag() { tags = "Hands" });
            item.Add(new Videotag() { tags = "Legs" });
            item.Add(new Videotag() { tags = "Balance" });
            VideoLV.ItemsSource = item;

            //VideoLV.selectedi = item[0];

            getvideo();
        }

        public class Videotag
        {
            public string tags { get; set; }
        }

        async private void getvideo()
        {
            allVideos = await DbFirebase.Getvideos();   

            //Adds videos to ItemsSource depending on the currently selected tag
            //videosListView.ItemsSource = allVideos.Where(v => v.tag.Trim().ToLower() == (VideoLV.SelectedItem).ToString().Trim().ToLower()).ToList();
        }
        //private void SfChipGroup_SelectionChanged(object sender, Syncfusion.Buttons.XForms.SfChip.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    videosListView.ItemsSource = allVideos.Where(v => v.tag.Trim().ToLower() == ((SfChip)chips.SelectedItem).Text.Trim().ToLower()).ToList();
        //}

        private async void Watch_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string videoId = (string)((ImageButton)sender).BindingContext;

            var video = allVideos.FirstOrDefault(v => v.id == videoId);

            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SingleVideo(video), false);
        }

        private void VideoLV_ItemTapped(object sender, Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {

            //var indexes = e.ToString();
            //String selectedFromList = VideoLV.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //int myindex = VideoLV.Index(tags);
            //vaVideoLV.selectedItem
            //var selected = (videotag)e.SelectedItem;
            videosListView.ItemsSource = allVideos.Where(v => v.tag.Trim().ToLower() == ((SfListView)VideoLV.SelectedItem).ToString().Trim().ToLower()).ToList();

        }
```

```
 <syncfusion:SfListView x:Name="VideoLV"
                             Padding="0"
                             AutoFitMode="Height"
                             Margin="10,0,10,0"
                             ItemTapped="VideoLV_ItemTapped"
                             BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                             SelectionMode="Single"
                             VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                             IsScrollBarVisible="False"
                             SelectionBackgroundColor="Transparent"
                             Orientation="Horizontal"
                             HeightRequest="55">
     
                                <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <Frame CornerRadius="10"  Margin="5,0,5,0"  BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HasShadow="False" >
                                            <Grid HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0" Padding="0"  >
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                            <Label Text="{Binding tags}" Margin="0,-5,0,0"  Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"  TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Frame>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <syncfusion:SfListView.SelectedItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <Frame CornerRadius="10"  Margin="5,0,5,0" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="Red">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding tags}" Margin="0,-5,0,0"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Row="0"  TextColor="Red" FontSize="Small" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Frame>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </syncfusion:SfListView.SelectedItemTemplate>
                        </syncfusion:SfListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to cast `SelectedItem` to `SfListView`, which is wrong

```
(SfListView)VideoLV.SelectedItem
```

the `SelectedItem` should be a `Videotag`

```
(Videotag)VideoLV.SelectedItem
```

Comment: videosListView.ItemsSource = allVideos.Where(v => v.tag.Trim().ToLower() == ((Videotag)VideoLV.SelectedItem).ToString().Trim().ToLower()).ToList();                                              Still returns as null ('Object reference not set to an instance of an object.')

Comment: just posting a line of code with no context isn't really helpful.  Are you having a problem with the change I suggested?  Do you have another question, or need clarification?  Note that you probably want to use `tags` instead of `ToString()`

Comment: I need the ToString() because the operand cannot convert Type string to list<char>. Where do i add 'Tags'?

Comment: literally replace `ToString()` with `tags`.  `tags` is the name of the `string` property on the `Videotag` class

Comment: `private void VideoLV_ItemTapped(object sender, Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
var getitem = (Videotag)e.ItemData;
string name = getitem.tags;

videosListView.ItemsSource = allVideos.Where(v => v.tag.Trim().ToLower() == (name).ToString().Trim().ToLower()).ToList();

}`

Comment: Solved my problem, thanks for all your help @jason

Comment: `name` is already a `string`, there is no need to use `ToString()` on it

Comment: its works so im over the moon. spent far to long on that.